# Xcode 7.1 crashes when simulator crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

I am running Xcode 7.1.1 on OS X El Capitan. Whenever I cause the simulator to crash, the Xcode application immediately crashes and prompts me to re-open Xcode. Does anyone know how I should fix this?

Comment: on which simulator? ios 8 or 9?

Comment: @dasdom - I have already filed a bug, and it seems that workarounds for this sort of issue exist for other versions of Xcode.

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati - I have not tried to reproduce this issue with an iOS 8 simulator, only iOS 9.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. < edit >The solution is to uninstall and reinstall Xcode, but you must make sure to do so correctly< /edit >. The following steps will uninstall and reinstall Xcode:

1. If Xcode is not visible in Launcher but is in /Applications, see if Xcode appears in Launchpad after typing `killall Dock` in Terminal. If it does, continue to the next step. Otherwise, drag Xcode out of /Applications and into the Trash and then empty the Trash. Then reinstall Xcode from the App Store, and continue on to the next step.
2. Xcode should now be visible in Launchpad. (If not, try restarting your computer and then typing `killall Dock` in Terminal.) Click on it and hold down until the icons begin to jiggle, and then click the X on Xcode.
3. For the next two steps, do not touch /Applications/Xcode.app in any way, shape or form. Do not move it or delete it or open it. (It is permissible to select it in Finder.) The next steps may take 20 minutes or more, so be patient.
4. Check if Xcode is still on your computer. Even if Xcode is not visible in Launchpad, it may still be in /Applications. Xcode is not truly gone until it is not present in /Applications. If you clicked the X in Launchpad, then Xcode will eventually disappear from /Applications; you do not need to do anything to delete Xcode except wait for it to be deleted by the system.
5. Check /Applications periodically to see if Xcode.app is there or not. Furthermore, make sure that the Xcode icon (if you have it in your Dock) is replaced by a gray question mark. **When you no longer see any indication of Xcode on your machine, you may reinstall Xcode from the App Store, and now it should work.**

Comment: So your answer is "reinstall Xcode"? You should probably say that at the beginning.

Comment: But... It seems to still happen every once in awhile and this is a time-consuming issue to deal with :(